# Angular 2 CLI Upgraded to latest and now ng serve gives me errors

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I upgraded to `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8` in my current Angular 2 CLI project, as well as updating my angular-cli.json to match the expected properties of the upgraded CLI. When I run ng serve, I get this error:

```
`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.getWebpackCommonConfig (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/learnloop/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/ng2/models/webpack-build-common.ts:23:25)
    at new NgCliWebpackConfig (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/learnloop/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/ng2/models/webpack-config.ts:13:30)
    at Class.exports.default.Task.extend.run (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/learnloop/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/ng2/tasks/serve-webpack.ts:19:22)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/learnloop/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/ng2/commands/serve.ts:84:26
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)`
```

I wrestled with this for awhile, but after running all of these commands and getting Angular CLI to not be in a broken state, I'm running into this issue. Here are the commands I ran:

```
`npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@webpack
rm -rf node_modules dist tmp typings
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@webpack`
```

And finally, here are the versions of node, npm, and Angular CLI that I'm running:

`Node v6.4.0
NPM 3.10.3
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8`

And here is my angular-cli.json:

```
`{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8",
    "name": "learnloop"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "main": "src/main.ts",
      "tsconfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
      "mobile": false,
      "prefix": "app",
      "root": "src",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "config/protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "config/karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "lazyRoutePrefix": "+"
  }
}`
```

I apologize for the huuuuge wall of text, but I wanted to make sure you all had everything you needed to potentially help with this. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Same issue with me after updating to current angular-cli.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work. Try pasting this into your angular-cli.json (edit it accordingly):

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8",
    "name": "<name-of-app>"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "lazyRoutePrefix": "+"
  }
}
```

Then type `ng init` inside of root project directory. It'll ask you to replace a bunch of different files or keep them. There are some slight differences between files, particularly inside of `app.module.ts` so make sure you commit first, as there will be some changes in file structure and code inside of the files.

Comment: @Steve Star The file is identical to the one generated by angular-cli current version, yet the console output are still seen.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your nodejs version to the latest (currently v.7.2). It worked for me with ng serve failing